# Unit Test getter

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jasmine

Trying to unit test a getter from an @Input (Angular 5), my test work for the setter (going for 100% code coverage) but I get warnings for the getter

```
private _triggerOnChange: boolean;
get triggerOnChange(): boolean {
    return this._triggerOnChange;
}

@Input()
set triggerOnChange(value: boolean) {
    this._triggerOnChange = value;
    this.ngOnChanges();
}
```

This gets me coverage for the setter

```
  it('should', () => {
    component.triggerOnChange = true;
     expect(component['_triggerOnChange']).toBe(true);
  });
```

But I can't seem to get coverage for the getter

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the packing value directly instead of accessing the getter. You should update your test to be:

```js
it('should', () => {
 component.triggerOnChange = true;
 expect(component['triggerOnChange']).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but I thought component.triggerOnChange = true is the same as component['triggerOnChange']

Comment: The first line uses the setter and the second line uses the getter.

Comment: Thanks a lot the approach. I was looking for this only.  I have an update that we have define the property in `beforeEach` scope and set them again in test case.This will cover both set and get methods.